# Getting Serial port info on Chrome Web Serial API

Tags: google-chrome, port, metadata

I'm using the Chrome Web Serial API. So far it's working fine, but now and I'm trying to get the (already opened) port metadata (port name, device ID, etc.) and I'm a bit lost.

Here are the steps to follow:
https://wicg.github.io/serial/#getting-serial-port-metadata
but so far I cannot get the information.

If I try by navigating the port class, the DevTools console trows "ƒ () { [native code] }".

I cannot find a suitable example of how to implement this. 
Does anyone have a hint?
Thanks in advance!!

Daniel.

Comment: Any updates on this topic?
Also have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it hasn't been implemented in Chromium yet. Keep in mind that the specs are sort of guides for vendors to follow when implementing a feature, but the actual shipped implementation can differ.

If you check the Web Serial API's code in the Chromium repo for Chrome [80](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/452afba8d3a59d2d256fa49fc7a925de302dbd11/third_party/blink/renderer/modules/serial/serial_port.h#L46-L56) (current version at the time of writing) and [84.0.4112.1](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/84.0.4112.1/third_party/blink/renderer/modules/serial/serial_port.h#L46-L56) you'll see that they only include the following methods:

```
open
readable
writable
getSignals
setSignals
close
```

You can read the latest comments on this API here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=884928

Comment: is this still available in chrome?